# Log4j 2 logs are being written in Log4j log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I added a jar which is using Log4j 2 for logging and my project is using log4j for logging. But I am getting log4j 2 logs in my projects logging file that I don't want. I am not sure how this is happening. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`log4j.logger.[packagename]=OFF` to `log4j.properties`.replace `[packagename]` by your jar's class package name.

Comment: How does it help??

Comment: Filtering class which  under the  specified package